# I can create a stored procure with invalid user defined function names in it

Tags: t-sql

I just noticed that I could alter my stored procedure code with a misspelled user defined function in it.

I noticed that at 1st time I execute the SP.

Is there any way to get a compile error when an SP include an invalid user-defined function name in it?

Comment: When you create or alter the SP it only checks that the SP compiles right, not that it runs right. You should be testing the code before wrapping it in the SP first IMHO versus just creating it on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

At compile time?  No.

You can, however, use some of SQL's dependency objects (if using MS SQL) to find problems just after deployment, or as part of your beta testing.  Aaron Bertran has a pretty nice [article](https://sqlblog.org/2008/09/09/keeping-sysdepends-up-to-date-in-sql-server-2008) rounding up the options, depending upon the version of SQL Server.

Here is an example using SQL Server 2008 sys object called [sql_expression_dependencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677315.aspx)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.scalarTest
(
    @input1 INT,
    @input2 INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @ResultVar int

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    SELECT @ResultVar  = @input1 * @input2

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @ResultVar

END
GO

--Fn Works!
SELECT dbo.ScalarTest(2,2)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.procTest 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 dbo.scalarTest(3, 3) as procResult
        FROM sys.objects
END
GO

--Sproc Works!
EXEC dbo.procTest
GO    

--Remove a dependency needed by our sproc
DROP FUNCTION dbo.scalarTest
GO

--Does anything have a broken dependency?  YES
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id) AS referencing_entity_name,
       referenced_entity_name, *
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies 
WHERE referenced_id IS NULL  --dependency is missing
GO

--Does it work?  No
EXEC dbo.procTest
GO
```